# Retrieve nested MongoDB object after querying nested object

Tags: mongodb

Given the following MongoDB collection `groups`:

```
[{
  _id: 'g1',
  name: 'Group 1',
  projects: [{
    _id: 'p1',
    name: 'Project 1',
    tasks: [{
      _id: 't1',
      name: 'Task 1'
    }, {
      _id: 't2',
      name: 'Task 2'
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I need to find `task` with `_id = t2` and return the whole `task` object:

```
{
  _id: 't2',
  name: 'Task 2'
}
```

I'm able to find the group, either using mongodb:

```
db.groups.find({ 'projects.tasks._id': ObjectId('t2') })
```

Or with Mongoose:

```
Groups.findOne({ 'projects.tasks._id': 't2' })
```

But of course, this returns the entire `group` document, and not the `task`.

I've tried:

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { 'projects.tasks._id': ObjectId('t2') }
  }, {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: '$chapters.sections'
    }
  }
])
```

But this throws an error.

Comment: Notice that there are multiple groups, each with multiple projects, each with multiple tasks. I don't have the _id of the parent group or project, only the _id of the task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query in a nested array and project only the matching items from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847406/how-to-query-in-a-nested-array-and-project-only-the-matching-items-from-array)